# Grouping and summarizing values

Tags: sql-server-2000

Find out makers who produce only the models of the same type, and the number of those models exceeds 1.

```
maker   model   type
 A      1232    PC
 A      1233    PC
 A      1276    Printer
 A      1298    Laptop
 A      1401    Printer
 A      1408    Printer
 A      1752    Laptop
 B      1121    PC
 B      1750    Laptop
 C      1321    Laptop
 D      1288    Printer
 D      1433    Printer
 E      1260    PC
 E      1434    Printer
 E      2112    PC
 E      2113    PC
```

The result should be

```
 Model  Type   
  D      Printer
```

I tried

```
   Select maker,type from Product
   Group by maker ,type 
   Having count(*)>1
```

The above query gives me the maker whose number of model exceeds one .But im not able to find the model which only produces same type .Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Distinct Maker, Type From Product
 Where Maker In (Select Maker From Product 
                  Group By Maker 
                 Having Count(Distinct Type) = 1 
                    And Count(Distinct Model) > 1)
```